# How to show calculation in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I need a help, anyone know how to process the calculation in Tkinter. I have tried to calculate my calculation in my program but its not working. This is my code, anyone know what is the problem is ?

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox as mb
import os

class calorie:
    def __init__(self, main, title):
        self.main = main

        self.main.title("Login to enter Workout Routine Program")
        self.main.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self)
        self.main.resizable(False, False)
        self.main.iconbitmap(default='')

        self.mycomponent()



    def mycomponent(self):
        mainframe = Frame(self.main, bd=50)
        mainframe.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

        frData = Frame(mainframe, bd=50)
        frData.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

        Label(frData, text='Height:').grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.entHeight = Entry(frData)
        self.entHeight.grid(row=0, column=1)

        Label(frData, text='Weight:').grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.entWeight = Entry(frData)
        self.entWeight.grid(row=1, column=1)

        Label(frData, text='Age:').grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.entAge = Entry(frData)
        self.entAge.grid(row=2, column=1)


        frTombol = Frame(mainframe, bd=5)
        frTombol.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

        self.btnCalculate = Button(frTombol, text='Calculate', command=self.prosesLogin)
        self.btnCalculate.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

        self.btnClose = Button(frTombol, text='Close', command=self)
        self.btnClose.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

    def prosesLogin(self, event=None):
        HeightUser = Tkinter.IntVar()
        WeightUser = Tkinter.IntVar()
        AgeUser = Tkinter.IntVar()
        Calculate = (10*WeightUser.get()) + (6.25*HeightUser.get()) - (5*AgeUser.get()) + (5)
        Answer = Calculate


        if HeightUser=='':
            mb.showwarning('Wrong input', 'Height cannot be blank!', parent=self.main)
            self.HeightUser.focus_set()
        elif WeightUser=='':
            mb.showwarning('Wrong input', 'Weight cannot be blank!', parent=self.main)
            self.WeightUser.focus_set()
        elif AgeUser=='':
            mb.showwarning('Wrong input', 'Age cannot be blank!', parent=self.main)
            self.AgeUser.focus_set()
        elif Calculate :
            #how to show answer ?
            mb.showinfo("Your Calorie is", Answer, parent=self.main)
            self.main.destroy()
            self.Close

        else:
            mb.showwarning('Wrong input', 'Wrong Input!', parent=self.main)
            self.Quit()

        def Quit(self, event=None):
            self.main.destroy()

        def Close(self, event=None):
            os.system('main.py')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()

    app = calorie(root, ":: calorie ::")

    root.mainloop()
```

The problem is, my calculation is not show up

Comment: Can you put the full code and the error which is showing up?

Comment: I already edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters you are using

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter
```

then mixing the two different uses so I'd highly recommend choosing one or the other.

Second you are clearly not looking at the terminal while the program is running because when I clicked on the calculate I got a variety of errors, primarily that `self.HeightUser / self.WeightUser / self. self.AgeUser` don't exist, you very clearly want `self.entHeight etc.` instead.

Then third you seem to have `def Close` and `def Quit` indented into `processLogin` but that might just be entering the code into stackoverflow.

---

Once you have dealt with the obvious errors then I notice you create `Entry` widgets and decide to use the newly created `IntVar`s instead which seems odd, it would make more sense to do:

```
HeightUser = int(self.entHeight.get())
```

the `int` is needed since the `Entry` data is a `str` although this would raise a `ValueError` if the input is invalid, so you could easily wrap it in a `try except`:

```
    try:
        HeightUser = int(self.entHeight.get())
    except ValueError:
        mb.showwarning('Wrong input', 'Height is not valid', parent=self.main)
        self.entHeight.focus_set()
        return
```

the `return` is to stop the function from continuing if the input was invalid, this way by doing the calculation after repeating this with all three fields it will only get to that point in the function if all three were valid:

```
    try:
        HeightUser = int(self.entHeight.get())
    except ValueError:
        mb.showwarning('Wrong input', 'Height is not valid', parent=self.main)
        self.entHeight.focus_set()
        return
    try:
        WeightUser = int(self.entWeight.get())
    except ValueError:
        mb.showwarning('Wrong input', 'Weight is not valid', parent=self.main)
        self.entWeight.focus_set()
        return
    try:
        AgeUser = int(self.entAge.get())
    except ValueError:
        mb.showwarning('Wrong input', 'Age is not valid', parent=self.main)
        self.entAge.focus_set()
        return

    Calculate = (10*WeightUser) + (6.25*HeightUser) - (5*AgeUser) + (5)
    Answer = Calculate
    mb.showinfo("Your Calorie is", Answer, parent=self.main)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `get` method of an `IntVar` to get its value, and its value is an `int`, not a string. That is, you don't do

```
if HeightUser == '':
```

This will never be `True`, because an `IntVar` never compares equal to a string.

Do this instead:

```
if HeightUser.get() == 0:
```

or more pythonically

```
if not HeightUser.get():
```

But there are other problems that I can't help you with without knowing what your program is supposed to do. For example, the `IntVar`s are never set, so their `get` will always return `0`. When and how should they be set? Depends on what your program is supposed to do.

Comment: My program is supposed to calculate calorie. user need to put their height, weight and age then user need to click calculate. After click calculate, the program will calculate based on this formula (10*WeightUser.get()) + (6.25*HeightUser.get()) - (5*AgeUser.get()) + (5) . But when i click on the calculate button, theres nothing happen